# Extract information from JSON output

Tags: python

I am trying to extract information from a JSON. I have been able to extract some parts without problem, but I have problems extracting strings at very low levels.

I got an output of what I need in this format. This I have stored in a list. Here is the example:

```
prices = [{'info': {'price': '2.00', 'desc': 'Up'}},
 {'info': {'price': '1.50', 'desc': 'Down'}},
 {'info': {'price': '3.00', 'desc': 'Down'}},
 {'info': {'price': '3.00', 'desc': 'Up'}},
 {'info': {'price': '8.40', 'desc': 'Down'}},
 {'info': {'price': '14.20', 'desc': 'Down'}}]
```

From this list I would like to extract the elements `price` and `desc` from each of them, stored in a list each.

I have tried to pass this list to a str string and use operators to search directly in the content, but I don't know how to do it in a simpler way.

Do you know a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is a serialization format. Once you've decoded it, its just python. In your example, `price` is a `list` of `dict` with a sub-dict. One option is to iterate the list, then get the dictionary information based off of known key names.

```
prices = [{'info': {'price': '2.00', 'desc': 'Up'}},
 {'info': {'price': '1.50', 'desc': 'Down'}},
 {'info': {'price': '3.00', 'desc': 'Down'}},
 {'info': {'price': '3.00', 'desc': 'Up'}},
 {'info': {'price': '8.40', 'desc': 'Down'}},
 {'info': {'price': '14.20', 'desc': 'Down'}}]

for data in prices:
    price = data['info']['price']
    desc = data['info']['desc']
    print(price, desc)
```

output

```
2.00 Up
1.50 Down
3.00 Down
3.00 Up
8.40 Down
14.20 Down
```

Answer (score 1):

```
price = [i['info']['price'] for i in prices]
desc  = [i['info']['desc'] for i in prices]
```